# Using AFNetworking to queue many JSON requests and save their responses

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I'm new to AFNetworking and I'm interested in using it to handle a few dozen JSON requests (for example, using a web service's API that responds with JSON) for my application, but I'm having some trouble understanding how I should do this.

Could anyone offer some insight on how I'd go about accomplishing this? Like I said, I'm new to the library so an explanation would be greatly appreciated if you explain with code.

For a more specific example as to what I'm trying to do, here's the Clear Read API I'm using, where you pass the URL as a parameter in the URL and are returned a JSON response (the API extracts the article from a URL, removing the other bloat).

Example URL: http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear?url=http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/02/27/uxstackexchange/&format=json

I'll be taking a few dozen URLs and running them all through that service and wish to save the results.

I was previously doing this with NSURLConnection in a for loop, firing off several dozen NSURLConnections, which was causing my data to be quite messed up by the end, with timeouts and whatnot from so many going at once.

I understand that it would be better to do only a few at a time, and AFNetworking seems perfect for this kind of problem, but I'm really just confused how I'd use it/subclass it or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with their [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking).

There's not much too it, really: build an `AFJSONRequestOperation` for each call to the API you want to make, and in the success callback, handle the deserialized JSON appropriately. If you have a bunch of calls to make, use `AFHTTPClient` to a) simply some of the repetitive work of building those operations, and b) use the client's operation queue to batch them all up. You can then throttle the number of requests in flight at once with the [queue's `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/setMaxConcurrentOperationCount%3a).

Comment: In the documentation, it recommends subclassing AFHTTPClient, is this necessary? Would I just use AFHTTPClient in an NSOperationQueue?

Comment: AFHTTPClient has an operation queue that it manages. It's not strictly necessary to subclass it (you can just instantiate one), but it can be helpful: your subclass can provide methods that build request operations specifically for your API, and that sort of thing.